# SonataAdmin + VichUploader not uploading image

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, vichuploaderbundle

I have set up VichUploaderBundle with SonataAdmin and I wan't to category entity upload image using sonata.

Form is rendered OK, entity save is Ok, send with multipart data and image is there. But it's not saved and there is no error or something to debug this.

config:

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
    category_image:
        uri_prefix: /uploads/images/category
        upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/images/category
        inject_on_load: true
        delete_on_remove: true
        delete_on_update: true
        namer: vich_uploader.namer_origname
```

CategoryAdmin:

```
        $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text', ['label' => 'title'])
        ->add('description', 'textarea', ['required' => false, 'label' => 'description'])
        ->add('image', 'file',
            [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'image',
                'data_class' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'sonata-medium-file'],
            ]
        );
```

CategoryEntity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="image_name", nullable=true)
 */
protected $imageName;
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     groups={"list"},
 *     maxSize="500k",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "constraint.mime_type"
 * )
 * @Vich\UploadableField(
 *     mapping="category_image",
 *     fileNameProperty="imageName"
 * )
 * @var File $image
 */
protected $image;
```

POST: content

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="s5519586317457[image]"; filename="ico.png"
```

Content-Type: image/png

[image: file form]

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/96#issuecomment-12135146) known issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to know with VichUploaderBundle and Doctrine:

- if the only field updated by the form is the file, Doctrine won't detect the change and it won't be persisted (this [link](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/known_issues.md#the-file-is-not-updated-if-there-are-not-other-changes-in-the-entity) explains why and how to work around that);
- the bundle triggers the upload mechanism only when `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` objects are present in the uploadable fields so defining a `data_class` option for your fields breaks that (you can safely remove it).

**N.B** : you might also want to check that your entity is defined as `@Vich\Uploadable`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forget to add '@Vich\Uploadable' annotation and removed data_class.

Comment: even without Sonata and having your suggestions implemented, the file still doesn't upload for me. $metadata = $this->reader->getMetadataForClass($class) in isUploadable($object) is returning null. how can I fix this?

Comment: @apfz I am facing the same issue. $this->reader->getMetadataForClass($class) returns null. Did you ever get around resolving the issue?

Comment: @IndivisionDev no I havent found a solution for it. But I remember very clearly, that without doing anything, the next day it just started working.

Comment: Usually, when `$this->reader->getMetadataForClass($class)` returns null its just a cache issue. Try clearing it.

Comment: @K-Phoen Yes, that was it. Drove me crazy until I figured that :)